# How convert string to integer in Oxygene

Tags: delphi, oxygene

In Delphi, there is a function StrToInt() that converts a string to an integer value; there is also IntToStr(), which does the reverse.  These functions doesn't appear to be part of Oxygene, and I can't find a reference to something that can do that.  How can it be done?

Comment: Delphi Prism is a compiler. It does not contain a library like Delphi win32 does. When using Delphi Prism you can use the full range of .Net classes and methods in the .Net library. It is the same library that C# and VB.Net uses. You might want to read about the subject in C# books or on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx

Comment: @Lars - That's not entirely accurate. Delphi Prism ships with a handful of DB connectivity components and design tools. So its not just a compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) function

try this

```
function StrToInt(S: String): Integer;
begin
  Result:=Int32.Parse(S);
end;
```

.Parse is pretty richly supported for multiple types.

Comment: You can also use Int32.TryParse(S, out intVariable) which returns a boolean indicating whether parsing the string into an integer was successful.

Answer (score 4):

RRUZ has the correct answer, but if you can't say good-bye to all the functions and classes you where used to in Delphi win32 you could take a look at [ShineOn](http://code.remobjects.com/p/shineon/). It's an open source library written in Delphi Prism to port Delphi win32 functions and classes to .Net. Not surprisingly it also contains [IntToStr and StrToInt](http://code.remobjects.com/p/shineon/source/tree/HEAD/trunk/Source/ShineOn.RTL/SysUtils.pas).